# Can I migrate some questions of mine from Superuser to here?

Tags: support, migration, unanswered-questions

I need to know if some questions of mine could be migrated here, if they are appropriate for this site and if by doing so I will get a chance to have them answered.

I write here after being advised to do so in [Superuser meta site](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6745/i-need-advice-on-where-to-move-some-questions-of-mine).

These questions were asked there, but they haven't received a lot of attention, and I'd like to try moving them somewhere else. The questions are:

https://superuser.com/questions/585295/how-to-customize-logout-options-under-linux

https://superuser.com/questions/584446/how-to-properly-configure-grub-settings-from-kde-system-settings

https://superuser.com/questions/586031/quick-usb-pendrive-formatting-under-kde

https://superuser.com/questions/584896/repository-to-upgrade-sigil-to-latest-version-on-kubuntu

Do you think that they have a chance of being successfully answered here? I'm rather new of the StackExchange network and I don't know if they are more appropriate (or have a better chance to be solved) on "Unix and Linux" or on "AskUbuntu".

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

General Linux questions are allowed on both sites. We usually point people to AskUbuntu if the question is Ubuntu-specific, and they point people to us if the question doesn't apply to Ubuntu at all. In your case, all of those questions would be fine here, although you might want to put [Repository to upgrade Sigil to latest version on (K)ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/584896/repository-to-upgrade-sigil-to-latest-version-on-kubuntu) on AU since it's specific to Ubuntu